# Is it possible for this Android LiveData/Threading code to give some kind of concurrency issue or unexpected result?

Tags: java, android, rx-java, android-livedata

I have some similar code throughout my project that is inside of my ViewModels which subscribes to an RxJava observable that is subscribedOn Schedulers.computation(). I have a `MutableLiveData<Integer> isLoadedLiveData` object that posts an updated int flag that will be observed in my activity.

Basically, in this `ViewModel`, if 3 subscriptions finish, then the `isLoadedLiveData` will be equal to 3 because each subscriptions adds to increments the int flag value of `isLoadedLiveData`. And in my `LiveData` observer of `isLoadedLiveData` in my activity, I then set up the views of that Activity once the int value is equal 3. So it lets me know that the `ViewModel` data is ready to go and each needed piece of data can be returned from each repsective getter. I do this so I don't need a bunch of LiveData objects in my Activity and can instead just have one flag that tells me when all my separate data is loaded.
Here is a section of the code in my `ViewModel`:

```
Disposable disposable1 = this.thingRepository.getThingSingle()
            .observeOn(Schedulers.computation())
            .subscribe(thing -> {
                name = thing.getName();
                abbrev = thing.getAbbrev();
                stuff = thing.getStuff();
                loaded++;
                isLoadedLiveData.postValue(loaded);
            });
```

Now I'll preface this by saying I am not well versed in java/android concurrency, so I am not exactly sure, but  I wouldn't think this code could give me some kind of problem. But I am not 100% sure. Could this possibly be problematic in certain situations, or will the sequence of code and threading not be an issue?

The data like `name`, `abbrev`, and `stuff` which are fields of my `ViewModel` are all returned to my Activity eventually (just through simple getters, no observers). Will these pieces of data always be correctly updated and safe to access from my Activity on the MainThread because the int flag being posted to `isLoadedLiveData` always occurs after the data is updated on the background threads. I am not completely sure because these values are being updated on a background thread and then the main thread accesses it. I don't know enough about concurrency.

This doesn't have much to do with RxJava but that is how I handle my threading in this case. It is more to do with Java Threading/Android Threading/LiveData in general. I am not completely sure how LiveData `.postValue` works, but I would assume it gets put in the main thread's Looper to execute my LiveData `Observer` callback with the posted value passed in. Will this no matter what always occur so that the values set above the `isLoadedLiveData.postValue(loaded)` are safe to access and correctly updated?

I appreciate any responses! Thanks.

Edit: Here is new code:

```
Disposable disposable1 = this.thingRepository.getThingSingle()
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .doOnSuccess(thing -> {
            name = thing.getName();
            abbrev = thing.getAbbrev();
            heavyOperationResult = heavyOpperation(thing);
            stuff = thing.getStuff();
        })
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribe(thing -> {
            loaded++;
            isLoadedLiveData.setValue(loaded);
        });
```

I added `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())` even though my repository returns a Single that is already subscribed on `Schedulers.computation()` just to express what thread it was subscribed on for the purposes of this example. I also added the `heavyOperation(thing)` just to show that I need it in the background because I do some computation that could take too long for the main UI thread.

Comment: anybody got an answer?

Comment: I wonder why you're using `observeOn` there. I would do the following: `.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation).observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` and then you don't need to use the `postValue` in there, just `value`

Comment: @ExpensiveBelly yeah, I actually just changed it to where I save state in doOnSuccess because there are some methods I call in order to save state that are heavy and I would like to occur on a background thread and not the main thread. I ended up doing setValue in subscribe after observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainthread()) for the isLoadedLiveData flag.

Comment: @ExpensiveBelly I had actually forgotten that all operators in RxJava occur in order, even if being run on background thread, so that is why I was updating the isLoadedLiveData flag from the background, when actually, I can just do that in my subscribe lambda on main thread signaling every rxjava operator before had finished, even if they occurred in background theads. So I just moved the saving state/heavy operatioins to doOnSuccess (which is occurring on Schedulers.computation()).

Comment: Could you please copy/paste your new code snippet so I can have a look? Thanks

Comment: @ExpensiveBelly I added it in the edit

Answer (score 1):

I disagree with that code snippet, you are mis-using Rx in my opinion.

Two things:

1. `doOnSuccess` is meant to be used for side-effects, not for doing heavy computations.
2. Do NOT take the state out of the Rx stream, pass it downstream instead. This statement `name = thing.getName();` and others like that inside `doOnSuccess` are really dangerous because you could have several streams modifying the same state in different threads.

What you want is to actually pass the state downstream and eventually publish it in LiveData, then you observe it as it changes.

```
 Disposable disposable = thingRepository.getThingSingle()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .flatMap(thing ->
                    Single.fromCallable(() -> heavyOperation(thing))
                            .map(heavyOperationResult -> new Pair<>(thing, heavyOperationResult))
                            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(pair -> {
                Thing thing = pair.getValue0();
                HeavyOperationResult heavyOperationResult = pair.getValue1();
                thingLiveData.setValue(thing);
                heavyOperationLiveData.setValue(heavyOperationResult);
            });
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response. I dont have a lot of experience with RxJava or development in general. I was wondering  why you use the flatmap with a map/subscribeon(computation) inside of it, instead of just mapping to the pair and subscribingon(computation) in the chain. Also the underlying emit (thing) of my single is never actually changed as it is data I need unchanged. I also didn't want lots of livedatas to observe in my activity, just one livedata loadedflag once all the rxjava Singles in my viewmodel are successfully subscribed to.

Comment: Then when that shows everything is loaded, the activity calls getters in my viewmodel (where the rx subscriptions occur).  But again, this might currently work for my specific scenario but I could envision scenarios where I could change state so you would be right about threading issues. As I said, I don't have much experience, so I may be thinking about this incorrectly, if so, please tell me, thanks! The code I had allows me to just have one livedata observed in activity, where I can then load a bunch of different views just with getters of strings (from my viewmodel) for presentation.